# markers are loaded on map but polylines are not showing up on google map with no error in code

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wrote the code according to documentation for polylines and i am not getting any error in code or no exception is thrown by code. even the app is running fine but polylines which should show up is not loading on map in my android app.

```
foreach (var route in routeList)
                {
                    if (route.RouteSegmentPoints != null)
                    {

                        Polyline polyline;
                        int color = Android.Graphics.Color.Black;
                        PolylineOptions poly = 
Utils.GetPolyLineOptions(color, 100, true, 100);
                        polyline = _map.AddPolyline(poly);
                        for (int i=0;i<route.RouteSegmentPoints.Count;i++)
                        {
                            point = new 
LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(route.RouteSegmentPoints[i].Latitude), 
Convert.ToDouble(route.RouteSegmentPoints[i].Longitude));
                            //endPoint = new 
LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(route.RouteSegmentPoints[i+1].Latitude), 
Convert.ToDouble(route.RouteSegmentPoints[i+1].Longitude));
                            poly.Add(point);
                        }



                        //System.Console.WriteLine("single Route");
                    }
                }
```

If anyone knows about solution please let me know thanks in advance.

Comment: From the looks of it you are adding the points _after_ you've added the polyline to the map.  Move the `_map.AddPolyline` call after the loop adding the points.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your suggestion i got it in the same way as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be assigning values to `poly` before adding it to the `_map`, so the values you add to it aren't passed in.

```
foreach (var route in routeList)
{
    if (route.RouteSegmentPoints != null)
    {
        Polyline polyline;
        int color = Android.Graphics.Color.Black;
        PolylineOptions poly = Utils.GetPolyLineOptions(color, 100, true, 100);
        for (int i=0;i<route.RouteSegmentPoints.Count;i++)
        {
            point = new 
LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(route.RouteSegmentPoints[i].Latitude), 
Convert.ToDouble(route.RouteSegmentPoints[i].Longitude));
            poly.Add(point);
        }
        polyline = _map.AddPolyline(poly);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work either, you could try wrapping the last line from my code to Run On the Ui Thread because depending on the thread this code is being executed on it may not be updating the UI:

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
    polyline = _map.AddPolyline(poly);
});
```

Comment: Thanks you i got it with this solution